# N-th occurence of a number in a vector

Tags: c++

Suppose I, have a integer vector <1,2,3,1,3,2,1,2> and I'm interested in finding the index of N-th occurrence of an integer in the vector(For eg, to find the index of third occurrence of integer 1, which is 7). How can I achieve this using iterators. Kindly help me with suggestions.

Thanks,
Sugmar.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Sounds like homework.

Comment: What's wrong with `std::find()` in a loop until either the *n*th match?  Or even `std::find()` with a predicate that can count?

Comment: Nothing..... ;) Or just a plain loop over the elements...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like

```
template<class InputIterator, class T>
size_t find_nth (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const T& val,size_t count)
{
    size_t ret=0;
    size_t index=0;
    while (first!=last) {
       if (*first==val)
       {
        ret++;
       }
       if(ret == count)
       {
        return index;
       }
    index++;
    ++first;
  }
  return -1;
}

int main()
{
   vector<int> myInt={1,2,3,1,4,1,5,6};
   int ret=find_nth(myInt.begin(),myInt.end(),1,3);//ret is -1 if not
   std::cout<<"index : "<<ret<<std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: returning -1 for function with return type of size_t is not a good idea

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be storing index per occurrence in map of element and vector of indexes as there can be multiple occurrences.

```
template<class T>
int findIndex(const std::vector<T>& v, T elem, size_t occurence)
{
    int ret = -1;
    std::map<T,std::vector<int>> mymap;
    int index = 0;
    for(auto elem:v)
    {
        mymap[elem].push_back(index); //storing index for same element it will be present in vector elements
        index++;
    }
    if(mymap.find(elem) != mymap.end())
    {
        try
        {
            ret = mymap[elem].at(occurence-1);
        }
        catch(...)
        {

        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```